# iPod touch sync problem - play counts

Tags: itunes, ipod, data-synchronization

An example situation:

Let's say I have a song on my iPod (in iTunes `Devices > iPod > Music`) and it shows a play count of, let's say 16. I disconnect my iPod, play the song, then connect it again and check the play count again. I would expect it to be, of course, 17. However the play count almost *doubles* every time (for a song with 16 plays, I suddenly got 31).

This is quite a problem for me, as I want to scrobble my tracks to last.fm, but I can't if my play count increases on some freaking exponential scale (when I do what I described above (disconnect, play the track once, connect + sync), the last.fm scrobbler suddenly has 16 scrobbles of the same song to upload).

Is there any known way to fix this? Most of discussions I read about this were years old and without any solution.

Comment: Do you 'manually manage music'?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the CloudScrob app that lets you preview the Scrobbles and edit them before it sends them.  Perhaps it could sidestep the bug?

Answer (score 0):

I've never run into this problem, the play count in iTunes works ok for me even with the iPod (or iPhone in this case). Maybe the last.fm scrobbler is doing something funny here?

You could try to use [ScrobblePod](http://code.google.com/p/scrobblepod/) instead which just looks at the most recently played songs and updates Last.FM accordingly.